# User Type Guest

Tags: profile, user, guest-user

Where and what is **User Type from Guest** so that I can create an exception in my rule?

Error Message: "Changing **User Type from Guest** to Profile External Client is not allowed"

Edit: I found it in my Process Builder, but where in Setup does it reside?:

[image]

Comment: If you have a Force.site or community, a user and profile is created for each SIte/community so that people can view pages without logging in.

Answer (score 0):

> but where in Setup does it reside?

You can get to see the details for Guest User by navigating from the Setup as below:

- Setup --> Site. You'll get to see all Sites/Communities as configured
  [image]
- Click on the Site/Community for which you need to view the Guest access details, and you will get to a screen as below
  [image]
- Click on the "Public Access Settings" to get details about the Guest User profile and the User assigned to it